# How to Set Minimum and Maximum Values in Hmisc Plots in R?

Tags: r, plot, hmisc

I want to plot all continues and categorical variables together.  How can I have minimum and maximum values in plots that I made by `Hmisc` R package?
If you have any suggestion about using of other R packages for this purpose it will be nice.

```
>hist(data,nclass=5, rugs=TRUE)
```

[image]